# Packer HCL2 validation returns "There is no function named formatdate"

Tags: packer, hcl

I'm trying to assign a variable in a Packer v1.9.4 HCL2 template:

```
variable "timestamp" {
  type = string
  default = formatdate("YYMMDDhhmmss", timestamp())
}
```

When I validate it I get the error in the subject:

```
Error: Call to unknown function

  on C:\Users\mathe\Documents\Azure Files\Packer Templates\avd-packer-win10-proto.pkr.hcl line 19, in variable "timestamp":
19:   default = formatdate("YYMMDDhhmmss", timestamp())

There is no function named "formatdate".
```

I'm confused because the [Packer documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/packer/docs/templates/hcl_templates/functions/datetime/formatdate) specifically calls out the `formatdate` function.

Has the `formatdate` function been removed or replaced? Am I missing a plugin or something?

Aside, is there a better way to assign a variable like this without using `default`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer is you can't call methods for Default values, or any kind of calculation / interpolation to result in the value passed.  Defaults must be constants.  Only local variables allow calculated values.  It's a business rule set by Hashicorp for security reasons, I believe.

This thread might help for context:

https://github.com/hashicorp/packer/issues/9430